# Custom WPF TreeView Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview, wpf-controls

I am trying to bind a collection of custom objects to a tree view's ItemSource in WPF with no success.

Here is the MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="AoiImageLift.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:AoiImageLift.UI.ViewModels"
    Height="500" 
    Width="500">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewViewModel.ProcessList}"/>
</Window>
```

Here is the App.xaml:

```
</Application>
    </Application.Resources>

        <!-- TreeView Style -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="Wafer"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ProcessList}">
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock
                                    FontFamily="SegoeUI"
                                    Foreground="MidnightBlue"
                                    Text="{Binding Wafer}"/>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                         </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                            Text="{Binding ProcessNumber}"
                            FontFamily="SegoeUI"
                            Foreground="MidnightBlue"/>
                     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
         </Style>
     </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Here is the MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private WaferSelectionTreeViewViewModel treeViewViewModel;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        BackgroundWorker initThread = new BackgroundWorker();
        initThread.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
        {
            e.Result = new SingulationOneTable().GetWaferList();
        };
        initThread.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            TreeViewViewModel = new WaferSelectionTreeViewViewModel(
                (List<string>) e.Result);
        };
        initThread.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public WaferSelectionTreeViewViewModel TreeViewViewModel 
    {
        get { return treeViewViewModel; }
        set
        {
            treeViewViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TreeViewViewModel");
        }
    }
}
```

FYI, this line of code...

```
e.Result = new SingulationOneTable().GetWaferList();
```

...simply returns a large list of strings.  That list of strings is then passed into the constructor of the WaferSelectionTreeViewViewModel class.

Here is the WaferSelectionTreeViewViewModel.cs:

```
public class WaferSelectionTreeViewViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Process> processList;

    public class TreeViewItemBase : ViewModel
    {
        private bool isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return isSelected; }
            set
            {
                if (value != isSelected)
                {
                    isSelected = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                }
            }
        }
        private bool isExpanded;
        public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get { return isExpanded; }
            set
            {
                if (value != isExpanded)
                {
                    isExpanded = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class Process : TreeViewItemBase
    {
        private string name;
        public Process(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.Children = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }

        public string Name { get { return name; } }
        public ObservableCollection<string> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public WaferSelectionTreeViewViewModel(List<string> waferList)
    {
        processList = new ObservableCollection<Process>();
        List<string> procList = new List<string>();
        foreach (string wafer in waferList)
        {
            procList.Add(wafer.Substring(0, 4));
        }

        IEnumerable<string> distintProcessList = procList.Distinct();
        foreach (string process in distintProcessList)
        {
            Process newProcess = new Process(process);
            List<string> wafersInProcess = waferList.FindAll(
                x => x.Substring(0, 4) == process);
            foreach (string waferInThisProcess in wafersInProcess)
            {
                newProcess.Children.Add(waferInThisProcess);
            }                
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Process> ProcessList
    {
        get
        {
            return processList;
        }
        set
        {
            processList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProcessList");
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone figure out why the items are not showing up in the tree view??

Regards,

Kyle

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of errors in your bindings. If you run your application from Visual Studio, you'll probably see one or more messages like this in the `Output` window:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: (...)
```

Firstly, each root item is bound to a `Process` object from `TreeViewViewModel.ProcessList` and it's told to display a property called `ProcessNumber`, but there is no such property, at least not in the code you posted. So I'm guessing the process items *are* showing up in the TreeView, but they're blank.

Secondly, your `HierarchicalItemTemplate` says that the list of child items can be found in a property called `ProcessList`. But each root item is a `Process`, which doesn't have that property, so no child items are displayed. You probably mean:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
```

Now, `Process.Children` is a simple list of `string`s, so you don't need to include the `<HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>` part (and of course, strings don't have the `Wafer` property that template is looking for).